# Если удалить обьект, то удалятся ли подписчики?

Tags: c#, события

Привет всем!

Ситуация такая: создал обьект класса, в нем подписался на события обьекта извне. Теперь, если я удалю подписчика, то удалится ли он автоматически в 
OnSceneChanged? Или его нужно сперва отписать, а потом удалить?

```
public class PassButton : Emitter {
    public delegate void OnSceneChangedHandler();
    public event OnSceneChangedHandler OnSceneChanged;
    public void SceneChanged(){// called from (scene changed)
        OnSceneChanged ();// Awake subscripters
    }
...
```

Comment: Что то вы замудрили. Это типичная утечка памяти. В общем если вы на кого-то подписались, то этот кто-то будет иметь ссылку на вас через делегат и пока вы не отпишетесь явно вас сборщик мусора не соберет. Потому нужно либо отписываться явно либо подписываться слабыми ссылками (что до ужаса неудобно реализовано)

Comment: Похоже Вы не поняли меня. Смотрите, обьект подписался на события. Потом этот обьект удалили (удалили подписчика). То есть ссылка на него в OnSceneChanged занулилась? Или все же сперва надо отписаться, а потом удалить уже не подписчика?

Comment: Откуда удалили подписчика? что это за "удалили подписчика" что не эквивалент "отписали подписчика"?

Comment: добавляю подписчика так: OnSceneChanged += func; Удаляю, в смысле теряю на него ссылку у себя. А вот это не вызываю: OnSceneChanged -= func.  OnSceneChanged не позволит мусорщику удалить обьект в таком случае?

Comment: да. не позволит. Мой первый комментарий как раз об этом.